# Creating flow map with matrix table using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, flow-map

I have a map http://prntscr.com/95zoyh and also data in a table (matrix table ) and I would like to have a map with different weight arrows depending of the data.

Is that possible to do using QGIS?

Comment: What does this matrix table look like? What are the rows and columns, and how does that relate to the lines on the map? Give examples if that helps.

Comment: you have people going from point 1 to 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9 then point 2 to 1,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9, etc. the lines are basically the path that the people need to follow to arrive at the points destination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the [FlowMapper plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/FlowMapper/). More explanation of how to use it: http://www.qgis.nl/2014/10/27/stromen-weergeven-met-flowmapper/?lang=en